# PHP Upload Wont Work, But Wordpress Upload Does

Tags: php, upload

I am creating my own upload script to upload files to my webserver (like small flash videos). However, it does not seem to be working. However, I don't think it is PHP because uploading files to my server via Wordpress *does* work.

Here is the upload form:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
   Video: <input name="vid" type="file" />
   <br/>
   Name: <input name="title" type="text" />
   <br/>
   Description:
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <textarea name="desc">Your description here</textarea>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
   </form>
```

Here is the upload PHP page:

```
<?php

 $target = basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 


 //check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
 if ($ok==0) 
 { 
 Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
 } 

 //If everything is ok we try to upload it 
 else 
 { 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 } 
?>
```

I have set the max upload size in php.ini to 100MB, however, the upload still fails. My php.ini file can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/nfz1ag7a) at pastebin. Also note that I have removed all verification from the upload script to see if it works.

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: What's in the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your code, you are uploading the file in the same directory as the running script. Are you sure you have write permission for the webserver in that directory?

Try uploading the file in your temp directory:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], sys_get_temp_dir().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$target);
```

and see if it works

**UPDATE**

You are calling your input file "vid" but you are trying to access the input "uploaded".

replace all your $_FILES occurences with $_FILES['vid'][]...

And enable error reporting on your machine

Answer (score 0):

How could you get the value of video from this:

```
$target = basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;
```

WHile the 1st block contain the name of the file which was given to the html.

IN your case it is :  `Video: <input name="vid" type="file" />` **Vid**

SO use this on your code:

```
<?php

 $target = basename( $_FILES['vid']['name']) ;
```